# Speed limit on streaming/downloading MP4 files

Tags: linux, bandwidth, streaming

Even though other file formats are downloaded fast, 
MP4 files are downloaded / streamed at max of 160 kb/s

I checked everything that may limit the bandwidth but couldn't find it.

How can i make MP4 files transferred faster ?

EDIT: H264 Streaming Module is installed (http://h264.code-shop.com/trac) 
mod_bwlimited is installed.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If I download an MP4 file it's downloaded at the same speed as any other file/format. Why would the fact that it's an MP4 file impact the speed at which it's downloaded? I'm not referring to streaming the content of the file I'm talking about downloading it as a file.

Comment: Maybe your network administrator has done something at the edge of the network to rate limit TCP streams that start with a `Content-Disposition` of `mp4`?

Comment: How exactly are you testing the bandwidth?  What happens if you test using curl?

Comment: I am testing it just by downloading from browser. My connection can download up to 800 kb/s but when i try to download from my server it doesn't go up more than 100 kb/s. Strange is that my friend can download at up to 1000 kb/s somehow. Is that possible that my server limit speed per connection ?